# TNS:name lookup failure

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have a stand-alone workstation at work that connects to an oracle database. It's been working fine for years and then all of sudden I get an error:

**[INTERSOLV][ODBC Oracle driver][Oracle]ORA-12545: TNS:name lookup failure**

When I ping the server I am trying to connect to from the command prompt, it replies back with the right IP address. If I do a TNSPING, that seems to be ok as well.

I have a separate PC that is on the computer network and it connects to the server just fine - it doesn't have that error above in bold.

There is another, different oracle database that I connect to on that stand-alone PC and it's still working fine. So, it's not like I lost the ability to connect to any or all Oracle databases - just something about this one.

I'm confused why it won't work and haven't had any luck trying to fix it. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the environment variable TNS_ADMIN to point at the location where your TNSNAMES.ORA file resides.

EDIT:

Can you connect with SQL*Plus directly?

If it's installed, this should work (replace user and db with the userid and database to conenct to):

```
sqlplus user@db
```

Failing that, try connecting with [EZCONNECT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT):

Modify sqlnet.ora file:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES,EZCONNECT)
```

Change your ODBC Connection in the Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration wizard to use the EZCONNECT string:

Replace the TNS Service Name with:

```
<db_host>:port/<db_name>
```

e.g.,

```
MYHOST:1521/MYDB
```

This points to the database MYDB on host MYHOST at port 1521 (the default port).

Try testing the connection. If that fails, try using the IP address instead of the hostname.

Given your TNSNAMES entry from your comments:

```
ESTRNP = (DESCRIPTION = 
           (ADDRESS_LIST = 
             (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ESTRNP)(PORT = 1521)) 
           ) 
         (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ESTRNP)) 
        )
```

You might try changing the CONNECT_DATA line to:

```
(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE = ESTRNP))
```

It is *possible* that the SID of the database was changed. Is this entry the same as the entry on the machine that works?

Comment: Under System Properties, Environment Variables, I have a variable defined as TNS_ADMIN with value c:\TNS_ADMIN and both my tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files are there. I had that done before I posted.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL*Plus. I first started getting the error from a .NET application that used the Oracle database. I then tried using "Oracle ODBC 32bit Test" and got the same error. I then went into my ODBC Data Source Administrator to delete and re-add the File DSN for that connection and I get the same error there now. I can't connect to it anywhere it seems, BUT, like I said, I can ping it from the cmd prompt and it sees it just fine with the right IP Address.

Comment: I tried the SQL*Plus route and got the following error: "ORA-12514 TNS:listener could not resolve SERVICE_NAME given in connect descriptor" ... I tried the same syntax with a different database that IS working and that gave me an error, too "could not resolve service name". I apologize, database design and connection is not my strong suit in general and Oracle is not my preferred database either. I only connect to it because a different team at my work uses it and I have to connect to it to get information. I briefly looked into the EZconnect route and am having no luck there either.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the database service name in your tnsnames.ora file is correct? Compare the tnsnames.ora file on the machine that works with the one that's failing. Can you post a sanitized version of the tnsnames.ora entry that fails?

Comment: I'm hard pressed to say 'absolutely sure', but I didn't mess with it or change it and it was working. Here's a snippit of it

ESTRNP =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ESTRNP)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ESTRNP))
  )

Comment: One more piece of information that may matter. The computer that works, logs in through a DOMAIN that our IT department sets up. We are a very large company. The computer that stopped working is an isolated workstation. I'm wondering if anything happened to the network or that server where it won't let me connect for some reason. I can still connect to another server just fine, but this one is hanging up for some reason. I'm not a network expert either, so I just don't know.

Answer (score 0):

do you have recently install any other oracle software?

It is possible that you have multiple `tnsnames.ora` files on different locations and the odbc driver finds the wrong one.

Inspect you path environment variable, whether the path to the right one is at the first place.

Comment: I do have a few folders I copied tnsnames.ora file to (and always have), but nothing changed. When I look at the files, they look right so far as I can tell.